# Is it possible to deploy API Manager in Anypoint Platform using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mulesoft

Using Axure Pipelines I have deployed Mule application in Runtime Manage of Anypoint Platform but is it possible to deploy API manage too using same pipelines and apply policies?

Comment: Hi Niladri, does aled's answer answered your quesion?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using just Maven then no. You need to use either the [Anypoint CLI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli) tool or somehow invoke API Manager REST APIs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion... but how can i use ANYPOINT CLI from Azure pipeline?

Comment: I guess you can use the command line task to execute the installation of Anypoint CLI and its execution with one of the `api-mgr policy` subcommands.